# Google Tango Lenovo Phab 2 Camera Intrinsics

Tags: google-project-tango

I was trying to extract the camera intrinsics and distortion coefficients from my Lenovo Phab 2 via [the documented](https://developers.google.com/tango/overview/intrinsics-extrinsics): 
`ret = TangoService_getCameraIntrinsics(TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR, &ccIntrinsics);`

Weirdly enough, the distortion coefficients are coming back 0 for every one. However, there is data for the intrinsics, with what I think is very low precision.

I thought at first it could have been a casting error, but with the `%f`, `%lf` and `%E` flags (`LOGE();`), the values don't change.

I know that on the previous Google Tango Tablet dev kit, the calibration coefficients and distortion modle was in a file called `calibration.xml`. Is this also true of the Lenovo Phab 2?

**EDIT**: After dumping the contents of the camera intrinsics struct to file, there is for sure no distortion coefficients being returned for the device. I.e. All distortion entries are `0.0000`.

Comment: phatty, could you check if you have `/sdcard/config/calibration.xml` file on your device? You can use `adb shell` to get into the device. If this file is missing, then you device is not calibrated.

Comment: @JasonGuo Did your device, or a known device have this?

Comment: @JasonGuo I looked in `/root/sdcard/config/` and did not find any `calibration.xml` file. However, there were two folders labeled `ocvfreak` and `lens_invariant_ocvfreak`. However, neither of these contain useful information; a couple `.p` files, which are, of course, inaccessible.

Comment: Yes, a well calibrated device should have this file. Do you have a rooted device? or it's a production device?

Comment: Also, try reboot the device. Rebooting the device will trigger TangoCore to copy the calibration persist path to sdcard/config. See if that fix your issue.

Comment: @JasonGuo Still no luck. I do not have a rooted device, and it is not a production device.

Comment: For some reason, you probably have a uncalibrated device. one more thing, could you send me the build number, you can get it form `adb shell getprop | grep ro.build.fingerprint`

Comment: Also, a serial number from `adb devices` would be helpful

Comment: @JasonGuo Do you work for Tango, or Lenovo?

Comment: Yes, I'm from Tango team. If you can give me above information, I can find out more information on this problem.

Comment: @JasonGuo I sent an email to the tango-support email that was on your website. I thought that would be a more appropriate channel then SE.

Comment: We try to route all coding/tech questions to Stackoverflow, meanwhile project-tango-help@ is going to handle only device issues. Your issue is kind of special, you probably get the device direct from Google or Lenovo? I am not sure if it actually passed through calibration process.

Comment: @JasonGuo I found that out, lol. Here is the build number: `[ro.build.fingerprint]: [Lenovo/phinny_na/PB2PRO:6.0.1/MMB29M/PB2-690Y_S100020_160924:user/release-keys]`. And the serial number is: `134e6df7`.

Comment: @JasonGuo I hope that you can fix my issue. This is frustrating. Is there a way you could intercept my email that was sent to project-tango-help? It highlights some of the issues.

Comment: can you contact me directly: xuguo@google.com

Comment: @JasonGuo I went ahead and sent you an email.

Comment: @JasonGuo I still have not heard back from the email I sent a message to: `xuguo@google.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with my device! It was resolved by receiving an updated device. Somehow the calibration data was missing.

Make sure to check your device for the calibration.xml file. If this file is not in-place, contact costumer support!